# the image in assets.xcassets display as a dashed box not as a image

Tags: ios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVxUs.png)

I add the image source to assets directly, it display as a dashed box, while I put them in a folder and then add them to assets, it display normally. who can tell me why?

Comment: the image link is here : https://ws4.sinaimg.cn/large/006tNc79ly1g24xxx3darj31bu0fg0uu.jpg

Comment: It shows a dashed box if you haven't added any images to it. The one you selected has images in it so it shows a preview of it. In this case its a white icon on a white background so it looks like a white box.

Comment: this is just another bug in xcode, this just happens to me also. restart the xcode and it will work just fine

Comment: @CraigSiemens I have  added the image，it still show a dashed box

Comment: @MohammadYunus my xcode is version 10.2，after restart  it still doesn't work

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show that you've added images to so we have no way of knowing that. Maybe the issue is having two assets with the same name.